# Redefine soap xsd (with external schemas) changing body with elements from an another xsd

Tags: java, xml, soap, xsd

Im trying to redefine the body of a soap xsd with elements from another xsd. The problem Im getting is about the schemas contained in the soap xsd. When I try to load everything in Java in schemaFactory.newSchema, I get this exception:

Failed to read schema document '/soap.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

The question is: how can I use redefine of a xsd containing other schemas ? It seems I cannot load them properly.

(Im using xsd:redefine tag)

Comment: You may later have difficulties with redefine (it's finicky), but at the moment your only problem is that your program cannot find the schema; make sure you know where it is, and make sure you're telling the program correctly where to look.  (Neither of these are nearly as simple in practice as they sound.)  Don't worry about redefine until you are able to load the base schema document.

Comment: Thanks for answering me.